# Apple store rejects Unity GVR app due to "Kids Category"

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, app-store-connect, google-cardboard

Publishing a unity ios app with GVR v.1.6 under the apple's "Kids" category,
app is declined due to VGR help button (the small '?' at the bottom left) which is activated when the setting button (at the top right) is pressed. According to iTunes Connect support "it includes links out of the app or engages in commerce without first obtaining parental permission".

As per GVR version 1.00 the "setting" button is embedded in the GVR and is it not editable. The `GvrView.setSettingsButtonEnabled` command has been deactivated from GVR 1.00.

Does that mean that IOS applications made with GVR version later than 1.0 cannot be published in I-tunes under the KIDs Category due to apple store's Guideline 1.3 - Safety - Kids Category?

Any help would be really appreciated!!

Comment: It sounds to me like you have answered your own question.

Comment: You might want to explain your situation here: https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-android-sdk/issues/252 or better yet, create a new issue.